# Azure DevOps - Custom Task - PowerShell with Azure Authentification

Tags: azure, powershell, authentication, azure-devops

So far I used the Azure PowerShell task to execute PowerShell scripts in an Azure Context (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=vsts). Due to generalization efforts I want now to create a custom task (see e.g. http://www.donovanbrown.com/post/how-do-i-upload-a-custom-task-for-build) that runs a PowerShell script in an Azure Context, i.e. that authenticates against a connection endpoint in Azure DevOps.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you need a service principal (see e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/create-azure-service-principal-azureps?view=azps-1.1.0) and a service connection (see e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=vsts).

In the custom task in `task.json` add an input to be able to select the service connection:

```
"inputs": [
        {
            "name": "ConnectedServiceName",
            "type": "connectedService:AzureRM",
            "label": "Azure RM Subscription",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "required": true,
            "helpMarkDown": "Select the Azure Resource Manager subscription for the deployment."
        }
]
```

In the task (the powershell script) you get this input via

```
$serviceNameInput = Get-VstsInput -Name ConnectedServiceNameSelector -Default 'ConnectedServiceName'
$serviceName = Get-VstsInput -Name $serviceNameInput -Default (Get-VstsInput -Name DeploymentEnvironmentName)
```

Then authenticate:

```
try {
    $endpoint = Get-VstsEndpoint -Name $serviceName -Require
    if (!$endpoint) {
        throw "Endpoint not found..."
    }
    $subscriptionId = $endpoint.Data.SubscriptionId
    $tenantId = $endpoint.Auth.Parameters.TenantId
    $servicePrincipalId = $endpoint.Auth.Parameters.servicePrincipalId
    $servicePrincipalKey = $endpoint.Auth.Parameters.servicePrincipalKey

    $spnKey = ConvertTo-SecureString $servicePrincipalKey -AsPlainText -Force
    $credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($servicePrincipalId,$spnKey)

    Add-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $tenantId -Credential $credentials
    Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId -Tenant $tenantId

    $ctx = Get-AzureRmContext
    Write-Host "Connected to subscription '$($ctx.Subscription)' and tenant '$($ctx.Tenant)'..."
} catch {
    Write-Host "Authentication failed: $($_.Exception.Message)..." 
}
```

**Edit:**

It is useful to clear the context at the beginning respectively the end of the script. You can do that via

```
Clear-AzureRmContext -Scope Process
Disable-AzureRmContextAutosave
```

at the beginning and

```
Disconnect-AzureRmAccount -Scope Process
Clear-AzureRmContext -Scope Process
```

at the end.

Comment: Could someone please direct me to the same implementation in typescript? I am able to get the endpoint through `let arm: any = tl.getInput('ConnectedServiceName', true);
let endpoint: any = tl.getEndpointAuthorization(arm, true);` But not sure how can I get the tenant/ clientId and secret etc.